EXIFTOOL: How do i use tag info (-filename) and use that to export a text file
I have a series of sony mp4 files that i would like to extract embeddedded info like shutter speed ISO etc. I was able to figure out formatting the info I needed.
However, I can't seem to get how to export the text file automatically. I want to export the txt file with the metadata in the same directory.
How can I use read information like -directory -filename, and use those to save the text file in the same directory with the original filename.txt?
Sony1Cam202403.mp4 to Sony1Cam202403.txt.
I'm using jExiftoolGuI V2.0.2 on M1 Mac.
I was able to get a file saved using >DIR. But this meant I had to change the name for every file that I wanted to gather metadata.
I've seen many ways to write tags, but how about writing filenames.

I can't help with the command atm (bah, jury duty), but what you want to look at is the -w (-TextOut) option.

Thank you. Using the -w command did everything i wanted.

You can use exiftool's -w (-TextOut) option to create a matching text file for each file that is processed.
The basic command would be this, replacing TAG# with the actual names of the tags you want to extract (see exiftool's FAQ #2/3 for the difference between tag descriptions and names).
exiftool -TAG1 -TAG2 -TAGn -w txt /path/to/files/

